# Webform submission tokens in emails

Tags: 8, tokens

I am trying to print the webform submission label and value from tokens in confirmation email. The problem is that the label of the form element is not appearing, only the value.
Tried with:

[webform_submission:values:email]
[webform_submission:values:email:withlabel]
[webform_submission:values:format:html]

When I print all the elements with [webform_submission:values] , I am able to see also the labels, but the formatting is not so good, so I want to print the values line by line.

Answer (score 1):

My solution is simply manually typing out relevant labels for each line.
I just use "Custom body"

For example:

Name: [webform_submission:values:navn:value]

Email: [webform_submission:values:email:value]

Date: [current-date:html_date]

Unless you change your form often i find that to be the easiest way to format it exactly as you want it.